# create_assignment function in moodle

Tags: odoo, moodle

I am working on integration of moodle with openerp.
Is there any function in moodle for create_assignment in moodle webservice. I found moodle_assign_get_assignment function in External service of moodle. But i wants create_assignmet function. Help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Moodle 2.8.x, have you tried assignment_add_instance?

I haven't yet but I use PHPStorm as an IDE and it hooks into all the Moodle API functions. So I just typed "assignment" and found that.

It is located in mod/assigment.lib.php line 36 and looks like this:

```
function assignment_add_instance($assignment, $mform = null) {
  global $DB;

  $assignment->timemodified = time();
  $assignment->courseid = $assignment->course;
  $returnid = $DB->insert_record("assignment", $assignment);
  $assignment->id = $returnid;
  return $returnid;
}
```

What I tend to do is I create an assignment on a test version of my Moodle, intercept the form before it submits and var dump the submitted form so you can see what you have to send into the function for it to work.

Good luck.

Of course, it may be:

```
function assign_add_instance(stdClass $data, mod_assign_mod_form $form = null) {
  global $CFG;
  require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/assign/locallib.php');

  $assignment = new assign(context_module::instance($data->coursemodule), null, null);
  return $assignment->add_instance($data, true);
}
```

That you have to call instead - cant remember which one superseded the other...